# Facebook SDK Integration in Android :Differenciate Error while refreshing Access Token through Facebook SDK.

Tags: android, facebook

We have integrated Facebook Login to our application. Once after first login, we refresh the Access Token of Facebook using below method.
We are finding difficulty in differenciating the errors returned when this call is made. The method OnTokenRefreshFailed returns exception with String message. It do not return me any error code. For my application I need to differenciate between authentication exception and network connectivity exception.So that I can code different experience respectively. Can anyone suggest me how I can differenciate exception here.

```
*AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync(new AccessToken.AccessTokenRefreshCallback() {
            @Override
            public void OnTokenRefreshed(AccessToken accessToken) {

            }

            @Override
            public void OnTokenRefreshFailed(FacebookException exception) {

            }
        });*
```